# Technic Medium Hub - What is the difference between Voltage L and S?

Tags: powered-up

As a computer science with limited Electrical Engineering Knowledge, I wonder what the `VLT L` and `VLT S` modes (and the Current counterparts) in the TechnicMediumHub (Control+ Hub) Voltage device are?

I am in process of writing a [.NET library for PoweredUp](https://github.com/sharpbrick/powered-up) where I want to present a human readable interpretation of it.

Below the dump of the Port(Mode)Information messages.

```
Port: 60
    IOTypeId: Voltage
    HardwareRevision: 1.0.0.0
    SoftwareRevision: 1.0.0.0
    OutputCapability: True
    InputCapability: False
    LogicalCombinableCapability: True
    LogicalSynchronizableCapability: False
    ModeCombinations: []
    UsedCombinationIndex: 0
    MultiUpdateEnabled: False
    ConfiguredModeDataSetIndex: []
    Mode: 0
      Name: VLT L
      IsInput: True
      IsOutput: False
      RawMin: 0
      RawMax: 4095
      PctMin: 0
      PctMax: 100
      SIMin: 0
      SIMax: 9615
      Symbol: mV
      InputSupportsNull: False
      InputSupportFunctionalMapping20: False
      InputAbsolute: True
      InputRelative: False
      InputDiscrete: False
      OutputSupportsNull: False
      OutputSupportFunctionalMapping20: False
      OutputAbsolute: False
      OutputRelative: False
      OutputDiscrete: False
      NumberOfDatasets: 1
      DatasetType: Int16
      TotalFigures: 4
      Decimals: 0
      DeltaInterval: 0
      NotificationEnabled: False
    Mode: 1
      Name: VLT S
      IsInput: True
      IsOutput: False
      RawMin: 0
      RawMax: 4095
      PctMin: 0
      PctMax: 100
      SIMin: 0
      SIMax: 9615
      Symbol: mV
      InputSupportsNull: False
      InputSupportFunctionalMapping20: False
      InputAbsolute: True
      InputRelative: False
      InputDiscrete: False
      OutputSupportsNull: False
      OutputSupportFunctionalMapping20: False
      OutputAbsolute: False
      OutputRelative: False
      OutputDiscrete: False
      NumberOfDatasets: 1
      DatasetType: Int16
      TotalFigures: 4
      Decimals: 0
      DeltaInterval: 0
      NotificationEnabled: False
```

Answer (score 2):

L and S very probably refer to load and supply voltage.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_load for details.

Experimentally, I have not observed any significant differences between these values in use (possibly because the source resistance is small).

Comment: I think you could be right with that... But I cannot set the answer yet to correct. Since it is speculation I guess.

Comment: There are LowVoltage = 0x01, HighCurrent = 0x02, and OverPowerCondition = 0x04 hub alerts. I could imagine there is a direct relation between these exposed alerts and the voltage / current modes.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an obvious difference between these two according to [a comment in the bricknil source](https://github.com/virantha/bricknil/blob/0610d8af76954b8b970956b86a5e59511b83389d/bricknil/sensor/sensor.py#L440):

> Voltage Sensor
>
> Returns the raw mV value (0-3893) which probably needs to be scaled to 0-9600.
>
> It contains two capabilities, although they both appear to do the same thing:
>
> - sense_l
> - sense_s

They appear to both return the same results in the same way.

There are some low-level ways that these could be different, but I'm not aware of efforts to reverse engineer the firmware and/or boards to that degree, and I'm not aware of documentation that covers this. The official [LEGO BLE docs](https://lego.github.io/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs/) don't go into this level of detail about the voltage sensor.

Here are a couple speculative possibilities:

- It is common for analog to digital converters to have different modes of operation that trade off speed and accuracy. VLT L and VLT S could make use of different sampling modes and/or averaging. For example, ST discusses using averaging to improve their ADC accuracy [here](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/c4/63/a9/f4/ae/f2/48/5d/CD00258017.pdf/files/CD00258017.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00258017.pdf) for the ST32 chips used in Powered Up parts.
- L and S could represent values at different stages in the power subsystem (e.g. regulated voltage vs battery voltage).
- These could be reserved for use in devices with multiple monitored cells. SPIKE Prime and Mindstorms both use 2 lithium cells in series. These cells are monitored individually, and it could be useful to access their values separately. This doesn't necessarily apply to Control+, but parts of the firmware are likely shared across devices.

I wish I had a better answer for you, but that's the best I could find from digging around. I hope that someone here knows more about this than I do. I'll certainly update this answer if I figure out anything more about this.

Comment: Bricknil source understanding is the same as mine. I think the different stages as outlined in the other comment is the best guess we might have.